# How to sum value in javascript array obj from specific search category to useState

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, use-state

I have js arr obj as below. My need is to sum value to useState base on category in the arr obj.

```
const [fit, setFit] = useState(0)
const [fat, setFat] = useState(0)
const [slim, setSlim] = useState(0)
const [test, setTest] = useState(0)

const arr = [
{id: '222', cost: 2, category: 'fit'},
{id: '333', cost: 3, category: 'fat'},
{id: '11', cost: 1, category: 'fat'},
{id: '11', cost: 0, category: 'fit'},
{id: '33', cost: 55, category: 'slim'},
{id: '55', cost: 33, category: 'slim'},
{id: '123', cost: 4, category: 'slim'}
]
```

How can i interate arr to get this effect ?

```
const [fit, setFit] = useState(2)
const [fat, setFat] = useState(4)
const [slim, setSlim] = useState(92)
const [test, setTest] = useState(0)
```

Thanks you for your help ;-)

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggested solutions? Is there a useful solution or a solution that you can mark as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `filter` to filter only the proper category, and then `reduce` to sum values

```js
const [fit, setFit] = useState(
    arr.filter(f => f.category === "fit").reduce((acc, c) => acc + c.cost, 0)
)
```

However, you'll need to do it for each state, which might be a little redondant, so I think it's best to have only one state, with a "category array" which you can map thru to create your state with X categories. Something like that

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(
    ['fit', 'fat', 'slim', 'test'].reduce((cats, currentCat) => ({
        ...cats,
        [currentCat]: arr.filter(f => f.category === currentCat).reduce((acc, c) => acc + c.cost, 0)
    }), {})
)
```

So if you need to add categories, you just have to add them in your array, and you can access each costs using `state.fit`, `state.fat`,...

Answer (score 0):

Just `filter` and `reduce`:

```js
const arr = [{id: '222', cost: 2, category: 'fit'},{id: '333', cost: 3, category: 'fat'},{id: '11', cost: 1, category: 'fat'},{id: '11', cost: 0, category: 'fit'},{id: '33', cost: 55, category: 'slim'},{id: '55', cost: 33, category: 'slim'},{id: '123', cost: 4, category: 'slim'}]

const sumBy = (arr, targetCat) => arr
    .filter(({ category }) => category === targetCat)
    .reduce((sum, { cost }) => sum + cost, 0);
    

console.log(sumBy(arr, 'fit'))
console.log(sumBy(arr, 'fat'))
console.log(sumBy(arr, 'slim'))
console.log(sumBy(arr, 'test'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

or you can create a reduced object once and receive amounts from it

```js
const arr = [{id: '222', cost: 2, category: 'fit'},{id: '333', cost: 3, category: 'fat'},{id: '11', cost: 1, category: 'fat'},{id: '11', cost: 0, category: 'fit'},{id: '33', cost: 55, category: 'slim'},{id: '55', cost: 33, category: 'slim'},{id: '123', cost: 4, category: 'slim'}]

const reducedObj = arr.reduce((acc, { category, cost }) => ({ 
  ...acc, 
  [category]: acc[category] ? acc[category] + cost : cost 
}), {});

// reducedObj looks like:
// {
// "fit": 2,
// "fat": 4,
// "slim": 92  
// }
// there is no 'test' so we make a guard while get values

console.log(reducedObj['fit'] ?? 0)
console.log(reducedObj['fat'] ?? 0)
console.log(reducedObj['slim'] ?? 0)
console.log(reducedObj['test'] ?? 0)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Comment: Did you try something like this? `[category]: acc[category] ? acc[category] + cost : cost || 0` it should remove `?? 0` in your console. :)

Comment: @Kordrad Actually, no. Because we don't know beforehand by which category user will try to get the amount.  And if this parameter is missing in the object, the user will get undefined.

Comment: good point, thank you for explaining

Answer (score 0):

You can create the function with reduce. Like this:

```js
const arr = [
  { id: "222", cost: 2, category: "fit" },
  { id: "333", cost: 3, category: "fat" },
  { id: "11", cost: 1, category: "fat" },
  { id: "11", cost: 0, category: "fit" },
  { id: "33", cost: 55, category: "slim" },
  { id: "55", cost: 33, category: "slim" },
  { id: "123", cost: 4, category: "slim" }
];
const sumArrBy = (arr = [], category = "") =>
  arr.reduce(
    (prev, { cost, category: cat }) =>
      cat === category ? prev + cost : prev,
    0
  );

console.log(sumArrBy(arr, 'fit'))
console.log(sumArrBy(arr, 'fat'))
console.log(sumArrBy(arr, 'slim'))
```

Then you can set your state like this:

```js
const [fit] = useState(sumArrBy(arr, "fit"));
const [fat] = useState(sumArrBy(arr, "fat"));
const [slim] = useState(sumArrBy(arr, "slim"));
```

Full code:

```js
export default function App() {
  const arr = [
    { id: "222", cost: 2, category: "fit" },
    { id: "333", cost: 3, category: "fat" },
    { id: "11", cost: 1, category: "fat" },
    { id: "11", cost: 0, category: "fit" },
    { id: "33", cost: 55, category: "slim" },
    { id: "55", cost: 33, category: "slim" },
    { id: "123", cost: 4, category: "slim" }
  ];
  const sumArrBy = (arr = [], category = "") =>
    arr.reduce(
      (prev, { cost, category: cat }) =>
        cat === category ? prev + cost : prev,
      0
    );

  const [fit] = useState(sumArrBy(arr, "fit"));
  const [fat] = useState(sumArrBy(arr, "fat"));
  const [slim] = useState(sumArrBy(arr, "slim"));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div>
        {fit}, {fat}, {slim}{" "}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The working demo you can find [here - codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-state-filter-d48hp?file=/src/App.js)

EDIT:
Other solutions for this issue have the "filter" function, which is not necessarily, because it makes another loop to filter values. In my case, I don't use the "filter". My solution is checking the category directly in the "reduce". It checks the category, and if the category is true, the function adds value cost to the results, if not, it skips and returns the previous correctly value.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't like the other answers. This one is different in that it will create an object based on all the properties in your array, dynamically uses `useEffect`, and only iterates through your array once.

```js
const arr = [
  {id: '222', cost: 2, category: 'fit'},
  {id: '333', cost: 3, category: 'fat'},
  {id: '11', cost: 1, category: 'fat'},
  {id: '11', cost: 0, category: 'fit'},
  {id: '33', cost: 55, category: 'slim'},
  {id: '55', cost: 33, category: 'slim'},
  {id: '123', cost: 4, category: 'slim'}
];

// reduce list to an object of total costs
const values = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
  if (!a[b.category]) a[b.category] = b.cost;
  else a[b.category] += b.cost;
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(values);

// create your values and setters in an object
const effects = {};
for (let key in values) {
  let [val, set] = useEffect(values[key]); // useEffect is not defined on StackOverflow
  effects[key] = {val, set};
}
/*
Creates obj with this structure:
{
  "fit": {
    "val": fit,
    "set": setFit,
  },
  ...
}
*/
```

Comment: Hey, look at my solution. I think is more clear, and also "only iterates through your array once", if you mean use only reduce without "filter".

Comment: "if you mean use only reduce without filter," yes I do. - "I think [my solution] is more clear," whether your solution is clear or not does not come into it, because your solution requires the manual entry of each value. Mine creates the `useEffect` variables as needed based on the `category` property of the initial array's objects. If there were 20+ unique categories my method is more far cleaner, though arguably yours is better articulated if there are only 3 categories.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the total cost without iterating over another time using filter.

Using reduce, we can add the cost with respect to category

```js
const arr = [
  { id: "222", cost: 2, category: "fit" },
  { id: "333", cost: 3, category: "fat" },
  { id: "11", cost: 1, category: "fat" },
  { id: "11", cost: 0, category: "fit" },
  { id: "33", cost: 55, category: "slim" },
  { id: "55", cost: 33, category: "slim" },
  { id: "123", cost: 4, category: "slim" }
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, { category, cost }) => {
  !acc[category] ? (acc[category] = cost) : (acc[category] += cost);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

**Result**

```
result =  { fit: 2, fat: 4, slim: 92 }
```

You can directly set that as a single state and access it as `data.fit`,`data.fat`, `data.slim`.

```
const [data,setData] = useState(result)
```

or

```
const [fit, setFit] = useState(result.fit)
const [fat, setFat] = useState(result.fat)
const [slim, setSlim] = useState(result.slim)
```